# RTweet new lookup_users continued excess error

Tags: rtweet

I was using R's RTweet lookup_users to successfully pull data on 6 IDs

```
test<-c("ID1","ID2","ID3","ID4","ID5","ID6")
    detail_followers <- lookup_users(users=test,
                                    parse=TRUE,
                                    token=[bearer_token here],
                                    retryonratelimit=TRUE, 
                                    verbose=TRUE)
```

Update: I created a loop so I could get more visibility on the run, which made it profoundly slow. This would be tolerable, except for two new problems. First, some lookup_user are missing the "profile_banner_url" variable. I built a function to check for this problem and insert a NULL value for those users missing it, further slowing the run.

Finally, many users in this set appear to be bots, as they are deleted within 24 hours of my having just pulled them from the API. The error provided from lookup_users is "Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors". is.atomic eval is not useful, because the fault occurs when lookup_user is called. There are far too many of these fake/suspended/deleted users for manual prompts.

These may be issues with the new RTweet from GitHub.